# DialogFragment show only the Buttons even the layout has more

Tags: android, layout, dialogfragment

As the picture show the `DialogFragment` It´s all white except for the Buttons. I have tried all kinds of layout parrams and `ConstraintLayout` settings but the white background feels like it´s some z-order thing,

Please advice
[image]

This is what the ANdroid Studio layout editor look likes

[image]

My xml:

```
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:srcCompat="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/place_search_dialog"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/place_search_dialog_header_image_IV"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:contentDescription=""
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline478"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        srcCompat:src="@drawable/place_picker_dialog_nobackground"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_place_dialog_cancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/cancel"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn_place_dialog_ok"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_place_dialog_ok"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/ok"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn_place_dialog_cancel"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline355"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.66"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_street"
        android:layout_width="74dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_place_dialog_cancel"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.348"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/place_search_dialog_header_image_IV"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.581"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/avatar"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline478"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.28"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**UPDATE**
This  is the DialogFragment

```
public class GooglePlaceDetailsDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private View mRootView;
    private BasePlace place;
    private Unbinder unbinder;
    RequestResponse requestResponse;
    private PlaceDetails placeDetails;

    public interface ShowPlaceListener {
        void onShowPlace(BasePlace item);
    }

    private ShowPlaceListener mShowPlaceListener;

    public static GooglePlaceDetailsDialogFragment newInstance(BasePlace item) {
        GooglePlaceDetailsDialogFragment fragment = new GooglePlaceDetailsDialogFragment();
        fragment.setPlace(item);
        return fragment;
    }

    // Called to do initial creation of a fragment.  This is called after onAttach and before onCreateView
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try {
            mShowPlaceListener = (ShowPlaceListener) getTargetFragment();
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Calling fragment must implement Callback ShowPlaceListener");
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment_show_google_place_details, container);

        ImageView imageViewStreet = mRootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_street);
        // Just unpack the details to make it smoother
        this.requestResponse = place.requestResponse;
        this.placeDetails = place.requestResponse.placeDetails;
        unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, mRootView);
        getDialog().setTitle("lkjkjlkj ");
        if (placeDetails.url.equals("")) {
            if (LogManager.isDebugable()) {
                Picasso.with(getActivity()).setIndicatorsEnabled(true);
            }
            Picasso.with(getActivity())
                    .load(R.drawable.anon_user_48dp)
                    .transform(new CircleTransformation())
                    .into(imageViewStreet);

        } else {
            if (LogManager.isDebugable()) {
                Picasso.with(getActivity()).setIndicatorsEnabled(true);
            }
            Picasso.with(getActivity())
                    .load(placeDetails.url)
                    .transform(new CircleTransformation())
                    .into(imageViewStreet);
        }
        return mRootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.btn_place_dialog_ok)
    public void onSearchClicked() {
        if (mShowPlaceListener != null) {
            mShowPlaceListener.onShowPlace(place);
        }
        dismiss();
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.btn_place_dialog_cancel)
    public void onCancelClicked() {
        dismiss();
    }

    private void setPlace(BasePlace place) {
        this.place = place;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        unbinder.unbind();
    }
}
```

This is the creation

```
 GooglePlaceDetailsDialogFragment dialog = GooglePlaceDetailsDialogFragment.newInstance(item);
            dialog.setTargetFragment(this, 0);
            DialogUtils.showDialogFragment(getFragmentManager(), dialog);
```

Util..

```
public class DialogUtils {

    private static String showDialogFragment(FragmentManager fragmentManager, DialogFragment dialogFragment,
                                             String fragmentTag, boolean onlyIfNotDuplicate) {

        // If only showing non duplicates dialogs, make sure the fragment isn't already in the manager
        boolean doesFragmentExist = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag) != null;
        if (!(onlyIfNotDuplicate && doesFragmentExist)) {
            dialogFragment.show(fragmentManager, fragmentTag);
        }

        return fragmentTag;
    }

    public static String showDialogFragment(FragmentManager fragmentManager, DialogFragment dialogFragment,
                                            boolean onlyIfNotDuplicate) {
        return showDialogFragment(fragmentManager, dialogFragment, generateFragmentTag(dialogFragment), onlyIfNotDuplicate);
    }

    private static String showDialogFragment(FragmentManager fragmentManager, DialogFragment dialogFragment,
                                             String fragmentTag) {
        return showDialogFragment(fragmentManager, dialogFragment, fragmentTag, true);
    }

    public static String showDialogFragment(FragmentManager fragmentManager, DialogFragment dialogFragment) {
        return showDialogFragment(fragmentManager, dialogFragment, generateFragmentTag(dialogFragment));
    }

    private static String generateFragmentTag(Fragment fragment) {
        return fragment.getClass().getName();
    }
}
```

Comment: set some width to your views!

Comment: can you show how are you making the instance of the dialogFragment and how are you inflating the dialog with the xml? thanks

Comment: The `ImageViews` have fixed width? Another strange thing is that the title text is missing, i dont remove it explicitly but set it it like `setDialog().setTitle("testtest");`

Comment: Thanks @JavierVieira I added some more code..

Comment: If I set background color to the ImageView´s then they appear but still the image not

Answer (score 1):

ok when I replace the `srcCompat:src=` with app:srcCompat=` the images show,  Strange that AS did not complain abut this typo